# Is There Any Way to Combine These Queries into One?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, join

I have two queries. I didn't knew how to make the same effect with only one. I'm not os good with SQL...

Here are pseudo-code:

```
friends = query("
    SELECT `bio_contacts`.`contact_id`
    FROM `bio_contacts`
    WHERE `bio_contacts`.`user_id` = '33'
")

query("
    SELECT `bio_community_events`.`id`, `bio_community_events`.`begin_on`, `bio_community_events`.`name`
    FROM `bio_community_events`
    WHERE `bio_community_events`.`user_id` IN friends
")
```

Is there any way to combine them into one query? It should improve performance, I guess. With joins, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query does not even need a join.
You could just say:

> SELECT `bio_community_events`.`id`,
>   `bio_community_events`.`begin_on`,
>   `bio_community_events`.`name`
>       FROM `bio_community_events`
>       WHERE `bio_community_events`.`user_id`=33;

Or -- are your field names a bit off, and should we join the following fields: bio_contacts.contact_id=bio_community_events.user_id ? In that case you can do
the following join:

```
SELECT `bio_community_events`.`id`, `bio_community_events`.`begin_on`, `bio_community_events`.`name`
    FROM `bio_community_events` INNER JOIN `bio_contacts` on `bio_community_events`.user_id=bio_contacts.contact_id
WHERE bio_contacts.user_id=33;
```

Comment: Bingo! 2nd query is what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT `bio_community_events`.`id`, `bio_community_events`.`begin_on`, `bio_community_events`.`name`
FROM `bio_contacts` 
LEFT JOIN `bio_community_events` 
ON `bio_contacts`.`contact_id`= `bio_community_events`.`user_id`
WHERE `bio_contacts`.`user_id` = '33'
```

Comment: Ye, this works. But this also returns 3 empty rows. Any way to fix that?

Comment: It's the LEFT join that is giving the empty rows. You may wish to change this to an inner join.